# Custom UITableViewCell: Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'pointsNumber'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My error is in the first code below, in the case 2 of the switch.

```
 cell.pointsNumber.text = "toto"
```

> Xcode error : Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'pointsNumber'

I can't access to my class `PerformancesViewCell` to fill the labels.
My cast doesn't work, my cell is still like a `UITableViewCell` rather than a `PerformancesViewCell`.

Thank you in advance for your help ;)

Cell Identifier:

```
let thirdCellIdentifier = "thirdCell"
```

TableView:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
 {
        var cell: UITableViewCell!

        switch indexPath.row
        {
        case 0:
            cell = tableViewProfil.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(firstCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            cell.backgroundView = nil
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            break;
        case 1:
            cell = tableViewProfil.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(secondCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DivisionsViewCell
            break;
        case 2:
            cell = tableViewProfil.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(thirdCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PerformancesViewCell
            cell.pointsNumber.text = "toto"
        case 3:
            cell = tableViewProfil.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(fourthCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChampionsViewCell
            break;
        case 4:
            cell = tableViewProfil.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(fifthCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            break;
        default:
            cell = tableViewProfil.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(fifthCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            break;
        }
        return cell
    }
```

CustomCell:

```
import UIKit

class PerformancesViewCell: UITableViewCell
{

    @IBOutlet weak var pointsNumber: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var challengesSucceed: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bestPosition: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var averagePosition: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var challengeCreation: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

Comment: why use tableViewProfil instead of  tableView, and where did you declare tableViewProfil?

Comment: I declared my tableViewProfil at the beginning of my class. TableViewProfil is an  @IBOutlet weak private var tableViewProfil: UITableView!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is because of this line:

```
var cell: UITableViewCell!
```

You declared cell as type of UITableViewCell . So as the error states the `UITableViewCell` has no member named `pointsNumber`.

Change that line:

```
var pCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(thirdCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PerformancesViewCell
pCell.pointsNumber.text = "toto"
```

Since you are using different type of cells and using a switch to distinguish between them, you need to assign the newly created cell(pCell) back to cell in the switch case itself.

```
cell = pCell
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! If i remove var cell: UITableViewCell! I can't return my cell at the end, because of the switch i need a declaration outside.

Comment: @MidhunMP I don't think you read the whole comment by Arthur. Your solution causes another big problem due to the `switch` statement.

Comment: @rmaddy: He edited his comment after my reply. Thanks for notifying

Comment: @Arthur: assign back it to cell variable, I mean in your switch case try to do this cell = pCell. Check my updated answer

Comment: @MidhunMp Yes sorry It was my first time on stackoverflow ! So i'm learning to use it ;). Yes it's perfect now, thank you for your reply, that's working well ! But i don't understand why i could not cast my variable in a PerformancesViewCell.

Comment: @Arthur: I don't understand your last question. Can you please explain little bit more ?

Comment: My mistake was to declared : var cell: UITableViewCell! , and after try to cast in PerformancesViewCell : cell = tableViewProfil.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(thirdCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PerformancesViewCell , I don't understand why i can't do that.

Comment: @Arthur: UITableViewCell is a base class of your PerformancesViewCell. So your class have all the methods and variables from the base class. But when you assigns cell = PerformancesViewCell() . You are actually doing a down cast. The variables declared in the derived class is unknown to it's base class, so you can't access it through a variable of type base class.

Comment: @MidhunMP Okay ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Midhun MP  's  answer.Generally,you should configure your custom tableviewcell class ,and  return them in each case.But if you want return a cell outside of the switch func ,you can do this trick:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
 {
    var cell: UITableViewCell!

    switch indexPath.row
    {
    case 0:
        cell = tableViewProfil.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(firstCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.backgroundView = nil
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        break;
    case 1:
        cell = tableViewProfil.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(secondCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DivisionsViewCell
        break;
    case 2:
       let  performancesViewCell = tableViewProfil.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(thirdCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PerformancesViewCell
        performancesViewCell.pointsNumber.text = "toto"
        cell = performancesViewCell
    case 3:
        cell = tableViewProfil.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(fourthCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChampionsViewCell
        break;
    case 4:
        cell = tableViewProfil.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(fifthCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        break;
    default:
        cell = tableViewProfil.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(fifthCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        break;
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend removing the `var` declaration of `cell` and instead use

```
if indexPath.row==0 {
let cell:MyCustomTVC=self.myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCustomTVC") as! MyCustomTVC 
cell.myCustomLabel.text="asdf"
return cell
}
```

for each case. Just swap out the correct class and identifier for each.

Also, make sure each custom cell type is defined in your storyboard using the prototype cells in the Attribute Inspector and all cells have an `identifier`

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! If i remove var cell: UITableViewCell! I can't return my cell at the end, because of the switch i need a declaration outside. Yes, all my custom cell and identifier are defined in my storyboard.

Answer (score -1):

This problem is not due to your code , happened with me due to changing classes name of view controller.

Xcode is not smart enough yet so, the solution is to delete the view controller that's crashing delete its class and create a new view controller and add a new file to it!!

took me days to get it fixed.